# Redirect only one page Page without affecting other urls with the nam in path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect a page:

```
http://www.mysite.com/samplepage/
```

Pages like `http://www.mysite.com/samplepage/samplepage2/` shall not be redirected.

This is my current .htaccess code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/samplepage/ /new-samplepageurl
```

The problem:
This one also redirects url's like:
`http://www.mysite.com/samplepage/samplepage2/`

Can I limit the redirect only to that one exact path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/samplepage/?$ /new-samplepageurl
```

The `$` sign marks the end of string, and `?` mark makes the trailing slash opional (e.g. both `/samplepage` and `/samplepage/` will be redirected)

Comment: how about /samplepage?page=200 will that be redirected to /new-samplepageurl without the extra parameter?